# Variável Javascript Para PHP vazia

Tags: php, javascript

Amigos estou com o seguinte codigo que, em parte, esta funcionando:

```
   <script>
$(function () {
    $(document).on('click', '.btn-danger', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault;
        var codigo = $(this).closest('tr').find('th[data-nome]').data('nome');
        var teste ='Teste';
       //alert(codigo);
    });
}); <?php$variavelphp = "<script>document.write(teste)</script>"; ?> </script>
```

porém tentei utilizar a $variávelphp dentro da mesma página e ela esta vazia tanto usando como "codigo" ou "teste" e no alert(codigo) ela aparece normalmente.

Answer (score -1):

Você não tem como passar valores do JavaScript para o PHP sem fazer uma requisição Ajax.

Para realizar uma requisição Ajax, escreva isto em seu código JavaScript:

```
function reqListener () {
  console.log(this.responseText);
};

var oReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
oReq.onload = reqListener;
oReq.open("POST", "http://seudominio_ou_ip/endpoint", true);
oReq.send("teste=TESTE");
```

Para capturar variáveis dentro do corpo de uma requisição, via PHP:

```
$body = file_get_contents('php://input'); // possui apenas o campo teste
```

Você pode até passar valores de variáveis do PHP para o JavaScript, mas tem que ser dentro daquela mesma página.

Comment: Amigo como faço isso pelo ajax.? você pode me dar um exmplo ?

Comment: eu pretendo usar o id do fornecedor para fazer um insert no banco e upload de uma foto para uma rrespectiva pasta